# Distributable fpga design

Tags: fpga, software-distribution, xilinx-ise

I'm new to fpga programming, and I'm wondering how to make my fpga design distributable.  Here's the scenario I have in mind.  I have a network of computers, each deployed with an fpga based peripheral.  I want to update the fpga design on the peripherals periodically.  How do I accomplish this without spending a fortune on software licenses?

I have a small dev kit for an fpga that shipped with an executable to load example design files (it was an Altera fpga FYI).  Does anyone know how I would create such an executable?

Some specifics:
My fpgas are Xilinx Spartan 6Es. I'm using Xilinx ISE for fpga development. The host computers are running debian linux.

Thanks for any and all advice!

Comment: You could add a small module to your FPGA design that can receive a new bit-file over whatever interface may be available, then program the flash memory with the new design. Alternatively, Impact does seem to have some command-line options available for running in batch-mode(see http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx13_1/pim_r_examples.htm for instance) although I've never tried it myself. Also - Impact can be downloaded for free as part of the Xilinx Labtools package.

Comment: Hey, thanks. That's the kind of answer I was looking for. As per your suggestion, one option would be to install iMPACT on all the deployed machines and remotely run through a shell script. I'm still wondering if someone knows how to do this through a binary executable file.

Answer (score 2):

If youre dealing with Altera: one computer would have the software tools and licenses needed to synthesize the project. Assuming all the FPGAs are the same model on each station/node, Quartus will generate an .sof file which you can copy and open from station to station. All you would need to do is download the Altera programmer tool (I believe you can download it separately from Quartus II) on each station which is free. Then upload the .sof to the board using the programmer, where you can permanently store it on the fpga prom using a technique similar to the following:

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrMe8JS7Ktk

However if you have Xilinx and Altera mix, Xilinx has .bit/xdl files, and uses another tool (impact) to upload their bitstreams. They can't be converted to and from bit and sof. So it's recommended that you probably stick to one make (Xilinx or Altera) and model based on your plans.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm familiar with tools you mentioned. So, with regards to the second part of my question, do you know if there's a way to package impact in some sort of executable? I've seen it done with the Altera programmer. I'm guessing there's a library you can program against, or something?

Comment: Yes it's the same way, except using the tool iMPACT as the programmer. You would generate a PROM file, synthesizing with xilinx ise first, which would make your "executable" (aka bitstream) to program the fpga.

Comment: Here's a link that will help you generate these files (it's for the spartan 3 but will be extremely similar for your spartan 6s) http://ece.wpi.edu/~rjduck/Spartan3_Tutorial.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are looking for is how to make your FPGA's field upgradable.  Assuming your FPGA is loading from an external memory such as an SPI flash chip, then you need to modify your design so that it is capable of writing to the SPI chip (or whatever) itself.  This is most simply done by putting a register in your design which maps to the individual pins on the flash chip, and then "bit bang" the register from a connected computer.  Assuming your FPGAs feed data into your own software running on the computer, then you would modify this software to have the functionality of manipulating this register to reflash the flash device.  Obviously, if this goes wrong you bricked your device until it can be flashed again with the JTAG, but it provides a way for all the devices to get updated in the systems they operate without needing to buy a JTAG cable for every single station.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Ethernet on your board you can use [the remote programming tool](https://www.fpga-cores.com/software/fpga-programmer/) from fpga-cores.

Then you can remote login to the network and program the FPGAs or mail the new config file to you customer and they run the programmer. This is how we remotely updates our boards.

Spartan 6 is supported. As a bonus you can also do some remote debugging with the remote logic analyzer.
Everything is free for non commercial use.